# Jit - Trying to resize SpaceTree on node expansion, rather than hiding the other subtrees

Tags: javascript, infovis, thejit, space-tree

I am working with Jit's Spacetree (http://flashcanvas.net/examples/thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html) and I am trying to modify it to where when you click on a node to expand it, it will not hide the other nodes, but it will simply resize to fit all of them on the canvas.

What I am trying to do is similar to the d3js's Collapsable Tree Layout (http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) . However, I cannot use d3js as the project that I am working on needs to be compatible with IE8 and as of now, d3js does not work with IE8 and the libraries I've seen around that try to combine Raphael JS and d3js are not working properly.

I am not looking for code, but simply an idea on how to implement that(whether it will be modifying Jit's source code or if I have to do it manually in my own .js file) Thanks.